# how to set mat card height for multiple mobile screen height (Angular 6)?

Tags: javascript, angular, css, angular-material-6

Currently, I am dynamically creating multiple mat-cards and setting the mat card height as

```
height: calc(100vh - 56px - 56px);
```

But this is not working efficiently for mobile with smaller screens (eg: iPhone SE). Should I hard code height for each mobile or is there any better solution?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Look into css media queries. Are you using angular material?

Comment: Yes @alt255, I am using angular material. media queries are similar to hard coding each mobile screen height.

Comment: Angular material has builtin `BreakpointObserver` which already contains breakpoints according to material spec for different devices. https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview